# If I buy shadow of revan expansion, do I become preferred?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I buy shadow of revan expansion, do I become preferred? Or do I have to buy something from the cartel market?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, anything bought from the website will make you preferred.